# Vue buildt doesn't show router pages

Tags: web, vue.js, web-applications, bootstrap-4, vs-web-application-project

I'm doing a webpage with Vue (Vue-bootstrap) and I'm having problems to make it works. I'm uploading the content of the **dist**  folder after using `npm run build`, the project was started using `vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack my-project. I've tried to add a **vue.config.js** file with the next information:

`module.exports = {
  baseUrl: './',
  //...
}`

I've try several times adding this in different folders before build it but I can't make it work.

The result just show the footer, it is in:
http://thegraph.es/Citython/

and the code without this **vue.config.js** is in the next link:
https://github.com/MGijon/Citython/tree/master/web

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but have you tried specifying the build type? e.g. `npm run build prod` for production? also, is your webserver where you're hosting your app properly configured for a single-page application?

Comment: I've tried and it does not work :(